# Storing a C++ header file globally in Windows

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2013, cimg

I'm using a library for image processing called Cimg. The library is stored in a single .h file (cimg.h).

I need to create several Visual Studio solutions(one solution for each exercise).

Where can I put this file globally so that I don't have to copy it to the Visual Studio solution each time?

Comment: Isn't there an "include paths" property you can set in a `.props` file?  I think the answer is "anywhere you want".

Comment: My knowledge of Visual Studio is very limited. I'll check your suggestion.

Comment: Include statements can use relative paths, so e.g. if you have all your exercise solutions under the one parent folder, you can put your include file in there and use `#include "..\cimg.h"` to get to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can put your header file anywhere you want, then add that folder as additional include directory for your visual studio project: Right click your project in the solution explorer, then:

```
Configuration properties->C/C++->General->Additional Include Directories
```

Just add the path there, and you can simply include CImg.h by:

```
#include <CImg.h>
```